# How to clear the preview image in form on submit but display it in the web page without any problem in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-forms

I was able to reset the input file image on submit in form but it has also cleared in the web page as well. I have to only clear the image on submit and display the image in the page.

[See the form image here][1]
[I want to display image like this on the web page][2]

Here is my code:

```
const [fileImage, setfileImage] = useState(null);
const handleImage = (event) => {
        setfileImage(URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
    }
 <div className="image-upload">
                       <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                <span>Image Upload</span>
                                <label className="custom-file-button"> <input
                                    type="file"
                                    onChange={handleImage} />
                                    Upload Image
                                </label>
                                {fileImage && (<div className="image-preview">
                                    <img src={fileImage} />
                                </div>)}
                            </div>
                            <div className="click-retrieve">
                                <button type="submit" className="data-saving">Save</button>
                                <button className="closing-window" onClick={toggle}>Close</button>
                            </div>
                      <form>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivcIe.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqbID.png
```

Answer (score 0):

it's the property of the "form" when you click on the submit button it refreshes the whole page, remove the form you don't need that, and remove the type="submit" as well from the submit button, and call the "handleSubmit" function bu the button, like this:

```
<div className="image-upload">
              
                            <span>Image Upload</span>
                            <label className="custom-file-button"> <input
                                type="file"
                                onChange={handleImage} />
                                Upload Image
                            </label>
                            {fileImage && (<div className="image-preview">
                                <img src={fileImage} />
                            </div>)}
                        </div>
                        <div className="click-retrieve">
                            <button  onClick={handleSubmit} className="data-saving">Save</button>
                            <button className="closing-window" onClick={toggle}>Close</button>
                        </div>
```